# How do you pipe different counters into a table using powershell?

Tags: powershell, pipe

In Powershell I am attempting to get counters for a process (winword.exe) and then put those into a table like so:

```
Process Name     CPU Usage(%)    Memory Usage(KB)
winword.exe      20%             234524324
winword.exe      15%             123343443
....
```

I can get the counters using get-counter \process(winword*)... but this diplays each individual counter information as a list even when I choose format-table.

How can this be done?

Comment: Please post the full command what you are using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the script which format exactly the way you asked for:

```
$a = @{Expression={$_.Name};Label="Process Name";width=15}, `
@{Expression={$_.ID};Label="Process ID";width=15}, `
@{Expression={$_.CPU};Label="CPU Utilization(%)";width=18}, `
@{Expression={$_.VM};Label="Virtual Memory(K)";width=18} 

Get-Process | Format-Table $a
```

Just save above as script and then run in Powershell and you will see the results as below:

```
Process Name         Process ID CPU Utilization(%)  Virtual Memory(K)
------------         ---------- ------------------  -----------------
chrome                     7080         65.8636222          340889600
chrome                     7668          0.8268053          199081984
chrome                     8512          4.3836281          168914944
```

You can modify the script to add/remove more columns and format as you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `-hidetableheaders`.